# Why does it not redirect me after the form has been submitted?

Tags: php, laravel

I have followed the Laravel documentation to perform user authentication and it has not redirected me to the page I wanted after I have put my correct email and password in the login screen.
The current result is that it just basically reloads the screen after entering the correct login details. The desired output is to be redirected to another screen. I have included some code of where I think the problem is. My GitHub repository will also be linked below in case you want to take a closer look, or running the code to see the problem for yourself. Also attached a zoom link, in case you want to hop on voice to educate me hehehe.
https://github.com/xiaoheixi/blog
https://uws.zoom.us/j/92387740659?pwd=K1NJdXhLRDRZWjZ3NFdsZUNvWE53dz09

UsersController@authenticate

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|exists:users,name',
        'email' => 'required|exists:users,email|email',
        'password'            =>  'required|exists:users,password'
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('/a');
    }
}
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::post('/authenticate', 'UsersController@authenticate');
Route::get('/a', 'UsersController@index');
```

Thanks for reading and trying to help me out! :smile:

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if you want them to go to `/a` then don't use `intended` ... also what do you want to happen on failed authentication? since there is no path for that ... also the route that goes to this method should probably be a POST route  ... are you hashing the password when saving the user? the password must be hashed

Comment: I got rid of intended. If the authentication has failed, I want the user to have to fill in their login details again. I have changed the route to a post in web.php and method=""post""in the form. But it still does not work, literally gives me the same result...

Comment: again ... did you hash the password when you created the user? the password must be hashed

Comment: What do you mean by hash the password, I am new to programming bro.

Comment: I didn''t hash, how do I hash? I know what hash means now I think.

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name'            =>  'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password'            =>  'required',
        ]);
        $adminContent = new User([
            'name'            =>    $request->get('name'),
            'email'            =>    $request->get('email'),
            'password'              =>    Hash::make($request->get('password'))
        ]);
        $adminContent->save();
        return redirect('/a');
    }

Comment: The code above Hash::make($request->get(''password')) gives me an error that says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Hash' not found

Comment: How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to redirect to url `/a`:

```
return redirect()->to('/a');
```